# statistical test for one quantitative and one categorical variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am new to statistics and am trying on random data sets,
one analysis what I am doing is trying to find if there is a relationship between two variables, duration and success where duration is numeric continuous variable and the other, success is categorical.

The distribution of duration variable is not normal, so I believe I am doing non parametric testing, what do you think?

- Size of the dataset: 45957 for both variables

Given the distribution of "duration" column, I have this fig:
[image: Duration distrubition]

Now I want to analyze what is the best duration/length of time to have a successful campaign, I visualize duration with all types of status:

[image: duration w/ status]

With the above relationship, there is no apparent conclusion, so I assume that success, is successful and rest all other categories are fail, I have this viz
[image: duration w/ match]

Now, I want to be sure, I want to perform a test to come to a certain conclusion.

I have never performed a statistical test in real life so I don't know what to do and how to proceed in practice.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the meanings of parametric/nonparametric. in particular, "parametric" doesn't imply an assumption of normality so non-normal doesn't of itself imply that you need to use nonparametric methods. Is your categorical variable ordered or nominal? What sort of relationships are of interest? In what sense are the datasets "random"?

Comment: If 'duration' has about the same distributional shape for Success and Failure, then a Wilcoxon rank sum test will help you see whether the Failure distribution is shifted in location relative to the Success distribution.

Comment: What about the distribution of the duration variable when it is restricted to each category? And do you see one as the response variable, such as control and treatment groups with “duration” measured?

Comment: The column duration is not normally distributed. Categorical variable, success, is nominal(success, fail) and the distributional shape of both variables is not same

Comment: The t-test, particularly for large sample sizes, is quite robust to deviations from normality. Perhaps most important, through: what do you see as indicating a relationship between the variables?

Comment: I want to test if there is a relationship, how else should I achieve that,  simple EDA says no relationship, but I want to establish a statistical proof.

Comment: What is a relationship, just that the distribution of durations for failures is different from the distribution of durations for successes? How does the EDA show that there’s no relationship? What would be a statistical proof to you?

Comment: I have updated my question, maybe that helps to explain my goal?

Comment: I notice that the highest modes in your plot of 'duration' seem to fall at numbers like 30, 60, 90.  If those are _days,_ the the question arises how and how accurately duration is being measured. I would really try to track down an explanation of these 'humps' in the duration dist'n before spending much more time trying to analyze the data. // Maybe explore a bit? What would be most useful findings (if true), Which categories are important? Etc. _Pay attn to @Dave's comments._ Then post a more definitive description of data and plan of analysis in a new question, referring back to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the Failure group has observed duration values  `x1`
and the Success group has values `x2`, as randomly sampled in R
below:

```
set.seed(624)
x1 = rgamma(100, 4, .09)
x2 = rgamma(100, 4, .12)
x = c(x1, x2);  g=rep(1:2, each=100)
boxplot(x ~ g, col="skyblue2", pch=19, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Then a two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum tests rejects the null hypothesis
that there is no difference in the locations of duration scores for
the two groups, with P-value 0.0023.

```
wilcox.test(x~g)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  x by g
W = 6247, p-value = 0.002322
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location shift is not equal to 0
```

*Note:* You don't say what your sample sizes are. With $n_1, n_2$ as large
as 100, group sample means might be nearly normal. In that case,
a Welch two-sample t test would be appropriate, But I wouldn't
want to do a t test for such skewed data if sample sizes are moderate,
say 20 to 40.

The P-value for the Welch test is also about 0.002, but there is
no reason to expect two-sample Wilcoxon and t tests will generally have P-values that agree so closely. So you should decide in
advance which test to use. (Not 'fair' to try several tests and
then pick the one with the smallest P-value.)

```
t.test(x~g)$p.val
[1] 0.002118171
```

Comment: Size of the dataset: 45957 for both variables

Comment: With sample sizes in the thousands, I think you could use a Welch 2-sample t test. However, 'duration' data might be prone to heavy skewness and far outliers. If your data are like that, then you should consider whether you want to compare 'locations' (as with Wilcoxon) or 'means' (as with t tests).

Comment: How would someone decide on that?

Comment: For a start, I'd be curious what is causing the multiple modes in your duration data. When you look at duration only for individual categories, do some of the 'humps' disappear? // Now you're mentioning additional categories, Live status, Suspended, etc. If these are all mutually exclusive categories, you might want to look at a Kruskal-Wallis nonparametric test first to see if there are any location differences among several categories; if so, use Wilcoxon tests _ad hoc_ to see where the differences are.